# It is acceptable for high rep users to delete posts that criticise them (even unfairly)?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete, ethics

In [a recent meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/354888/timeline#history_f110e9ba-b5a3-4d6f-8f49-c5519abc620f), there was a user criticising a gold-badge holder that he closed a Stack Overflow question in error.

The result? The specific gold badge holder, together with two other people, deleted the meta post.

Regardless of whether the closing of the original was correct or not, does the stack overflow community believe that we should delete posts that involve us?

Comment: He only voted to delete the post, along with 2 others

Comment: @gnat: Definitely related, not sure if it is an *exact* duplicate though. Maybe I should add the tag [specific-question].

Comment: In the USA you only lose the right to vote when you are convicted of a felony, like murder or treason.  Or if Trump knows the last 4 digits of your social security number, perhaps.  He's spent plenty of time in county jail, that doesn't qualify.  It is *just* one vote, not enough to delete anything.  The OP communicated very poorly, that does have a knack to get to a "oh shut up already" outcome.  Never post to meta mad-as-hell or under the influence of recreational drugs.

Comment: @Hans I don't thing I've ever posted on Meta sober.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The general guideline for deleting questions is found [in its privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), emphasis mine:

> Closed questions that are of no lasting value **whatsoever** should be flagged and deleted.

One can make arguments that a temporal question that deals with a specific question being closed isn't going to be very lasting, but...then with that logic, Meta couldn't really be a place to discuss or call into question...questionable moderation of content.

I'm usually the guy walking around here who sees a silver lining to most of these clouds, but my usual pattern is as follows:

- Any rant or ramble deserves a delete vote.
- Any question asking why a decision was made...likely doesn't.
- Any question with a suitable answer that is succinct and to the point *should* be preserved.

In this case, [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354892/1079354) clearly explained the rationale behind closing questions in general (a side effect of the unfortunately over-broad reach of the OP), and also addressed their *specific* question.  Even in the comments there, its dupe closure was also questioned, which would've likely sparked follow-up moderation on it.

From my perspective, that question **should not have been deleted.**  At worst, it stands for the OP to reference.  At best, it would've allowed further moderation and analysis on the question at hand by others who are more qualified to look at it.  Even if the answerer were dissatisfied or frustrated with the OP, the best thing to do in that scenario is to disengage entirely as opposed to inciting collateral damage.

Answer (score 16):

> Regardless of whether the closing of the original was correct or not

That's not to be disregarded at all.  If the post *merits* the moderation actions, then those actions are fine.  By all means, be more suspicious of a user, and look a bit closer at the post to ensure that the actions are indeed justified, if there's a reason for bias there, but the fact that a post criticizes someone doesn't prohibit them from acting on it.  If it did, then I could post a meta question just filled with personal insults for everyone I can possibly come up with, along with other highly disagreeable statements, and they'd all be prohibited from voting to close/delete the obvious troll post.

**If** you're able to demonstrate that a user *inappropriately* used a moderation action specifically because that post said something that they disagreed with, then that's a big deal, and by all means, raise a flag (or even using the "contact us" form, if appropriate) about that as an issue, explaining what problem you think happened.

Comment: I am not at all an expert in the technology that was covered by the question, so I really have no opinion on the duplicate. But meta is about discussing moderation actions, so even if the original SO question was indeed a duplicate, the meta post was on-topic in my view. Also your counter-example doesn't seem right to me, there is a difference between criticising everybody and just one person. In the first case anybody can and should moderate, in the second case why can't the person affected let the rest of the community do the moderation?

Comment: @user000001 So you *do* want to discuss whether this specific posts merits closure, not just whether it's fundamentally wrong for anyone to vote to delete a post if they are called out in it or disagree with it?  As for the community weighing in, lots of people voted to close and delete the question; the user just cast *one* vote, of eight.  Clearly the community had plenty of say in what was going on there.  Again, if you have reason to believe that they acted in bad faith, and intentionally abused an action, present a case for it, but someone deleting a post that merited deletion is fine.

Comment: Which post are you talking about? the SO post or the meta post? The topicality of the SO post is orthogonal to the need of the meta post to be deleted. Don't you agree?

Comment: @user000001 Indeed, the topicality of the SO post is irrelevant.  You (from my understanding anyway) said that the close-worthiness of the meta question is irrelevant, and yet that's what you're discussing.

Comment: Oh I see now that my wording was a bit ambiguous. I meant the close worthiness of the SO question is irrelevant to this discussion. About the meta post, I guess that if he genuinely believes that it should be deleted, he has the authority to vote, but I just found it suspicious that he decided to vote to delete the *specific* post that was questioning his decision. Like a conflict of interest scenario.

Comment: @user000001 It's a bit of a concern for someone with unilateral deletion power, which is why you'll see mods avoiding deleting posts calling them out (even if they merit deletion) unless they really have to (i.e. no one else is around, particularly on small sites, and it's an egregious post that can't sit around), but here, as mentioned, this is one of many votes, clearly quite a few community members all though that this post was quite problematic.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with said Meta question is that in its initial revision, it was the umpteenth variation of *"I disagree with a gold tag badge holder's duplicate close vote because my question isn't answered by the duplicate, should gold tag badge holders have these privileges?"*.

In its current version, the OP of that question is going out of their way to explain why they aren't required to create a [Minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), both in the question itself and in comments under my self-deleted answer.

In other words: the question is off-topic, because:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community.

They disagree with the closure, they don't want to provide a MCVE and they want to take away power from gold tag badge holders, simply because they're unable to create a question others can answer.

We've had enough of such questions already, this one doesn't add anything to the existing ones. That's why I voted to delete.

It really doesn't matter that one of the delete-voters was the addressee of the question. The question has no value; it's merely a rant.

On the other hand, if a Meta question is on-topic, it won't be close-voted, it can't be deleted and we won't have this discussion.

Answer (score 6):

From the site's rules point of view it is perfectly valid to downvote/vote to close/vote to delete any post based on the post's content alone irrespective if post mentions you or in any way related to you.

From ethics point of view I would avoid voting on such question as it could be viewed as conflict of interests (unless it is clear spam).

Comment: Clearly, the site rules are wrong. Nobody should take action (other than flagging) on a post that is about them, whether that's voting up, down or closing/deleting.

Comment: I am pretty sure that in that case a third vote would come as easy as the two came in this case. But I agree, there is a conflict there.

Comment: Not wrong, it is a very basic premise of democracy.  Who do you think, say, Macron voted for?  If it was Le Pen then he should be thrown out with a no-confidence vote.  Hehe.

Comment: @HansPassant: There is a difference between a general election vote than consists of 60mn people, and a case where 3 votes determine the outcome. A better analogy would be to compare with faculty elections/court decisions, where the number of voters is much smaller. In these cases conflict of interest is taken very seriously.